# Disable 'View Feature Details' panel on geocortex

Tags: geocortex, geocortex-essentials

Does anyone know if its possible to disable the ability to drill down from the initial results panel to the additional feature details panel? My feature description has all the feature attributes I'd like to display so wish to disable the next step. I have made the attributes invisible so the Additional Feature Details are blank. . [image]

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you've seen [this answer](https://support.geocortex.com/essentialsGSCForum?sub-nav=forum&main-nav=essentials&#!/feedtype=SINGLE_QUESTION_SEARCH_RESULT&id=906f2000000k9ebAAA) in the GCE support forums, but for the next guy who hasn't:

> I would try removing the command parameters under the "behaviors" section of the "Results" module in the json config file.  You'll want to try this on a test site and make a backup of the json file first.

Comment: Removing the command in the Desktop.json has worked great for disabling the ability to drill down to the Feature Details. However, I am still left with the arrow on the results panel indicating "Click here to view feature details" (see pic above). When I click the arrow now I stay on the results panel but I'd like to user not to see the arrow.

Comment: You can remove the arrow with CSS from the custom css files in the viewer's directory.